# Random Sort does not terminate

Tags: java, sorting, random

Assuming isAscSorted functions as expected (tested)
I am doing something silly here which is why random swap never sorts the array - because it is only ever doing 1 swap each time on different arrays?

My test case is
        int[] values1 = new int[] { 50, 10, 20, 4, 5, 1, 5 };

Hints?

```
public static boolean isAscSorted (int[] arr){

    for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
        if (arr[i]> arr[i+1]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public static boolean swap(int[]a,int i,int j)
{
    if (i == j){
        return false;
    }
    int temp=a[i];
    a[i]= a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
    return true;

 }


static int randomSort(int[] values) {

    //Ok Array is empty or null
    if( values == null || values.length==0){
        return 0;
    }

    boolean isSorted = false;
    int steps = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    int limit = values.length-1; //SOL: should be int limit = values.length;


    while (!isAscSorted(values)){
        //choose 2 random positions
        int r1 = r.nextInt(limit);
        int r2 = r.nextInt(limit);

        //swap returns true if successful
        boolean swapRes = swap(values, r1,r2);

        //increment steps counter
        if (swapRes)
            steps++;

    }

    return steps;
}
```

Comment: Does isAscSorted return true if there are the same values in a row?

Comment: returns true for { 1, 4, 5, 5,10, 20, 50 }, { 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6 }

Comment: Isn't the condition for the `while` wrong? I mean, you should keep doing it while the values are sorted. Since you're doing it while it's not sorted, your random algorithm will take a lot of time to put it in order

Comment: How did you get the idea for random sort? It is a little bit non sens.  Test with much smaller array first (something like 3 elements). Try also with almost sorted array in order to increase the chance for solution.

Comment: Piyin No, the loop condition is correct. The problem was with 
limit = values.length-1.
Meant the final index position was never randomly selected and so the array would never get sorted no matter how many swaps were made.

Comment: Please don't edit the **question** to add the solution. Instead write an **answer** and **accept** it. It is totally fine if you're writing the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was with the use of Random. 
I had indicated int limit = values.length-1;
This meant the last array position was never swapped and so the array could never be sorted (unless the 2nd and last numbers were identical and maximal for example).